# Listing Staff projects

Tags: mysql, sql

I have made these tables:

Table 1 (Job Title)

```
JobTitleID |  JobName
2432          Software Developer
3462          Data Designer
```

Table 2 (Development)

```
SoftwareID | StaffID | JobTitleID
3337         2363      2432
4636         2363      2432
6676         2436      2432
3432         2363      2432
```

Table 3 (Staff)

```
StaffID | FirstName | Last Name
2363      John        Smith
2436      Fraser      Morgan
```

Table 4 (Software)

```
SoftwareID | SoftwareName
3337         Iphone
4636         Android
6676         Windows
3432         Playstation
```

And I want to be able to list the names of the `Staff` table who have the job of `Software Developer`, with how many development Software projects they each have done, in order from least to greatest.

Something like this:

```
FirstName | LastName| Project Count
John       Smith      3
Fraser     Morgan     1
```

Additional Info:

- JobTitleID is the `PK` of table `JobTitle` and the `PFK` of table `Development`.
- StaffID is the `PK` of table `Staff` and the `PFK` of table `Development`.
- SoftwareID is the `PK` of table `Software` and the `PFK` of table `Development`.
- The three tables: `Job Title, Software, Staff`, all each have mandatory one to mandatory many relationships connected to `Development`.

I have been trying something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, COUNT(*) AS numProjects
    FROM Staff
        INNER JOIN Development ON Staff.StaffID = Development.StaffID
            INNER JOIN JobTitle ON Development.JobTitleID = JobTitle.JobTitleID
                WHERE JobName = 'Software Developer'
                    GROUP BY FirstName, LastName;
```

Is there a way I can achieve a query work that will for my problem?

Any hep would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Staff.FirstName, Staff.LastName, COUNT(Development.StaffID) AS numProjects
  FROM Staff
     INNER JOIN Development ON Staff.StaffID = Development.StaffID
        INNER JOIN JobTitle ON Development.JobTitleID = JobTitle.JobTitleID
           WHERE JobTitle.JobName = 'Software Developer'
              GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

Output:

```
FirstName - LastName - numProjects
  John    -  Smith   -     3
  Fraser  -  Morgan  -     1
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `count(*)` with `count(distinct SoftwareID)` should do. And also the distinct after select is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT FirstName, LastName,
 COUNT(*) AS numProjects 
 FROM Staff, Development, JobTitle
 WHERE JobName = 'Software Developer' 
 AND Staff.StaffID = Development.StaffID 
 AND Development.JobTitleID = JobTitle.JobTitleID 
 GROUP BY StaffID;
```